# aes decryption in c#

Tags: c#, encryption

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography;


namespace login
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    string dbprovider;
    string dbsource;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string username = "";
    string password = "";



    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        username = textBox1.Text;

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage2);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'login_data1DataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.table1TableAdapter.Fill(this.login_data1DataSet.Table1);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbprovider  = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"; //If you’re an avid fan of Google you’ll see this line written in a number of different ways, version 12(this one) is suitable for our version of access.

        dbsource = "Data Source = ../login data1.accdb"; //Change this for the location and name of your db.

        con.ConnectionString = dbprovider + dbsource;

        con.Open(); //If you get this far you’re db is now opened successfully.
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT username FROM table1 WHERE username = @username", con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("your username was not right");
            reader.Close();
            command.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            username = textBox1.Text;
            reader.Close();
            OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT password FROM table1 WHERE password = @password", con);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);

            OleDbDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();


            if (!reader2.HasRows)
            {
                // if (reader2.ToString != textBox2.Text)

                MessageBox.Show("your password was not right");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("logged in");
                tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(1,tabPage2);
                password = textBox2.Text;
            }


            reader2.Close();
            command2.Dispose();
           }
            con.Close();

    }
    }
}
```

so I made this login script for c# that connects to my database, but i was wondering how do you decrypt the database,as my current database has aes encryption, and i want the program to decrypt it so that I can answer the correct username and password, however anyone who has access to the database sees random strings, thanks in advance

Comment: You should read up on salted, hashed passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't need to encrypt passwords with AES and decrypt them back (if you're doing this - you have to store AES key somewhere, and this can be insecure).

Instead just apply some **cryptographic** hash function (SHA2, for example) to original password and store this hash in database.

When user enters password - you're applying this hash function to the password entered by user, and this will give you hash. 
Then you're just comparing this hash with one saved in database.

Thus you don't need to decrypt password at all.

Comment: Don't use just any hash function. Use one specifically design for password hashing, e.g bcrypt.

Comment: @Codo reasonable addition, I've added remark concerning cryptographic hash function, not just any. But I'm not sure if bcrypt more suitable than SHA2 I've suggested initially.

Comment: bcrypt is more suitable. It uses several rounds to achieve a cost of approx. 100ms per hash, which is a good compromise between a high cost for hackers and a low cost for your IT system. Furthermore, it returns a handy string that includes the salt and all other bcrypt parameters. If you use SHA2, you have to build all this yourself.

Comment: BTW: Your answer doesn't mention salting, which is essential.

Comment: PBKDF2 (via `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`) is is the most appropriate KDF inbox on .NET

Comment: @bartonjs I agree, but you are unfortunately limited to SHA1 with `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.  There are bcrypt implementations on NuGet that would likely be a better choice.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Technically SHA2 is not suitable at all and never was.  It is a message digest, not meant for password hashing.  It is extremely fast to compute and thus a very poor password hashing method.  PBKDF2 or bcrypt should be the recommended options here.